# subquery with population and percentages

Tags: postgresql

I need some help writing a subquery. I have columns where I need to take a percentage of a population but based on some other column.

| state | pop | column_a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nyc | 10 | 1 |
| ny | 15 | 1 |
| nyc | 20 | 0 |
| ny | 25 | 0 |

I need to sum the populations by column_a equals 1 over the whole population based by state.

something like below is the desired outcome.

| state | % |
| --- | --- |
| nyc | 50.0 |
| ny | 37.5 |

I have tried window functions, subqueries (not my strength), I am not sure how to craft subquery.

```
-- numerator

select
    state,
    sum(population)
from table
where column_a = 1
group by state
order by state;

-- denominator

select 
    state,
    sum(population)
from table 
group by state
order by state;
```

This is as far I get, I am not sure how to combine these two queries to yield the table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgresql you can filter element to sum with FILTER parameter. This way the query comes very simple.

```sql
SELECT
  state,
  sum(pop) FILTER (WHERE c=1) / sum(pop)::float AS avg
FROM data
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY state
```

This results:

| state | avg |
| --- | --- |
| ny | 0.375 |
| nyc | 0.33333 |

Comment: Hi! thank you for this! I hope you are having a wonderful day! This was the right answer. I am so thankful for your insight. I learned about the filter parameter which is so helpful! I also learned that Round doesn't take a float, but Round does take a numeric which just plug-in, play at that point. Seriously, thank you!

Comment: Hi @Mike! Good to hear that helped you. I would appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select n.state,
    n.n /d.d
From (select
    state,
    sum(population) n
from table
where column_a = 1
group by state ) n
Join (select 
    state,
    sum(population) d
from table 
group by state) d on n.state = d.state
order by n.state;
```

This will work correctly where all states have values for both numerator and denominator.

Comment: Is there a way we can make it simpler? I don't think join is the best solution. I will have to repeat the process for other columns. My problem has column a, column b, and c. Each column a, b, c has their own 1s & 0s. So my desired outcome solution will go from left to right.

Comment: Even if you exclude join, the complexity of query won't change a lot. If you've a lot of columns, unpivoting them first might help